# unzipping the file in Front end

Tags: javascript, jszip

I am sorry that I dont have sandbox of the what I have and what I wanted but I have tried to explain it here, Please let me know if this is not enough.

I had a function in code named downloadFile which was fetching a file with this code:

```
const downloadFile(url){
   const res = await fetch(url);
   return new Uint8Array(await res.arrayBuffer());
}
```

now i want to change this code to accept the url of a file which is zipped.
I am using JSZip for unzipping the file.

Since I can not change the other part of code outside this function, I used jsZip and JSZip Utility to unzip a file

```
const url = "./autonomyteamvumi.ford-vumi-ext-0.0.31.foxe.zip";

downloadFile(){
          JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, async (err: unknown, data) => {
            if (err) {
              throw err; // or handle err
            }
            const data1 = await JSZip.loadAsync(data);
            console.log(data1);
            return data1;
          });
}
```

Looking at the previous code, looks like I need to send typedArray of unzipped data or something but this is what data1 console looks like:

[image]

Anything that you can suggest

Comment: [getBinaryContent(path, callback)](https://stuk.github.io/jszip-utils/documentation/api/getbinarycontent.html). Then, from there: [loadAsync(data [, options\])](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/load_async.html)

Comment: @Ouroborus Thank you so much, I am sorry I did not understand what you are suggesting? I should put loadAsync outside ?

Comment: I'm just linking to docs, follow the examples they have. Once you have the zip loaded and processed, you can extract the content of individual files with [.file(name)](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/api_jszip/file_name.html).